# Inserting data from both sides in many to many relationship

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two entites, groups and actions which have m:n relationship. From UI, actions can be added to groups and vice versa. Associative table contains "group_id" and "action_id" columns, so both entities have "hasmanytomany" relationship specified. Now, how to add/remove items from both ends i.e,

```
newGroup.Actions.Add(newAction);
```

and

```
newAction.Groups.Add(newGroup);
```

From documentation, specifying inverse allows to modify only from one end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use add and remove methods on my entities that do this for me.  Below is an example of a User/Group scenario.

```
public class Group : Entity
{
    //Constructors and properties omitted

    public virtual void AddUser(User user)
    {
        if (users.Contains(user))
            return;

        users.Add(user);
        user.AddGroup(this);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveUser(User user)
    {
        if (!users.Contains(user))
            return;

        users.Remove(user);
        user.RemoveGroup(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Cole. If possible, can you please post the code for AddGroup and RemoveGroup methods too.

Comment: @Sundeep they are the exact same except for the collections they add to.  Replace "user" with "group" and you have the methods.

Comment: Now, I understand how this happens. NHibernate only allows insertion from non-inverse side in m:n relationship. These helper methods will help inserting from inverse side by attaching the owner and making it look like it is actually inserting from non-inverse side.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what they do.